# Redux - Dispatching Actions Correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my app, I had small action creator functions which returns an action for a small section of the app. My rational being that I wanted to be as 'precise & specific' with my logic, yet keeping the code reusable.

To give an example, I have React 'tab' components which are reused on everywhere. In one scenario, clicking the 'tab' would -1- Make the tab active, -2- do something else that is required. In someother scenario, clicking the 'tab' would -1- Make the tab active, -2- do something else, possibly different to the first scenario above.

The logic I thought of was that I would dispatch two action creators in each scenario above. The first is obviously the common one, the second one is unique to each scenario.

```
// rough code for illustrative purposes
activateTab : () => {
 dispatch( actionCreator1 );
 dispatch( actionCreator2 );
},
render: () => {
 <Tab onclick = { activateTab }
}
```

PROBLEM(?):
I occured to me that each action creator being dispatched would call reducer functions & then make React run its 'differing' algorithm. I.e. In the above `Tab`, React is recalculating all the DOM changes twice? Is this correct? Can someone please confirm?

And how should these scenarios be handled?

Should I be making an action type (& thereby action object) unique to each scenario? Which would mean, there should be only one dispatch function.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be making an action type (& thereby action object) unique to each scenario?

Presumably you are already doing this, if you are dispatching two different actions correct? I think you do not need the `SET_TAB` action, if you never use it on its own, the only thing you need is to listen to more actions in your reducer.

In any case, your assumption is correct, and it's totally normal to have one reducer listen to many different actions. Consider your active tab reducer to look something like:

```
let initial = {
  fooActiveTab: 0, // first foo tab is open
  barActiveTab: 2, // third bar tab is open
}

function activeTab (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case 'SOMETHING_RELEVANT_TO_FOO':
    case 'FOO_AJAX_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        fooActiveTab: action.payload // set current tab
      }

    default:
      return state

  }
}
```

This makes your reducer composition very clear, as the tabs state listens to a variety of things that may change what the active tab is. This way you do not need to dispatch two actions on every function call.. just one is enough as long as you send along the id of the tab you want to be active.

I think you *should* do the above, but not to prevent React from running the diff algo.. but to be more organized. React's diff / patch will run **A LOT** and your app will still be very fast. Any slowness you perceive is due to components actually updating because the DOM needs to change, and not because of [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

Comment: Thanks Azium. The takeaway is that I should create unique 'action-types', however, within the reducers, the 'switch -> case' should focus on returning the little changes. After all, all reducers get called upon all actions. Thanks again.